# SSRS 2012 - Dynamically change value of textbox in report header

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

I am in the process of converting some MS Access 2003 reports to SSRS 2012 (using VS 2010 to develop the reports).  I have a report with a number of parameters.  Some of the parameters are populated dynamically from a query (Location, Client, etc).  The report header is set up in the following way:

REPORT TITLE

Location

Date

Detail data tablix (Type, size, etc)

There is a grouping on the Location ID value.  Each page of the report is for each location selected from the Location parameter list (ie New Jersey, New York, Washington, etc).  I get the following error on the Location text box:
The Value expression for the text box 'Location' refers directly to the field 'LocationName' without specifying a dataset aggegate.  When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

The first function just shows the first location in the list on each page.  I tried to use Lookup function, but still got the same aggregate error.

I know there has to be a way to do this.  (I am new to SSRS, but learning VERY fast.)

Thank you - Susan

Comment: Is this really a DBA question? Seems to me more like a developer's question for StackOverflow.

Comment: You might look at this blog post [change value of textbox in report header](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/26/fields-in-page-header.aspx). I don't know if it is exactly what you are trying but you can download the RDL file from the blog post as reference.